# Project is missing its references and I'm using nugets

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cK6z.png)

My project is missing its references, I tried to restore the Nuget packages but still references are missing

Comment: This happens if the file of the reference can't be found. Maybe something got deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be references deleted, or if you are using nugets then it is not restored.

but, I would suggest you first to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks, i am using some nugets , but how can slove this?

Comment: right click on your solution, and select the option "Restore NuGet Packages" , don't forget to mark this question as answered :)

Comment: I click "Restore NuGet Packages", as if nothing had happend,- -

Comment: delete the content of you local package folder and then restore again . this should work

Comment: I delete the package folder and try again, have dialog box is displayed briefly,and package folder come back ,but the yellow flag still in.

Comment: can you restart your studio and Clean and re-build the solution?

Comment: https://github.com/comwrg/Os     this git url

Comment: yes, restart and try again

Comment: and ? still issue persist ?

Comment: yes, you can push back git and open look

Comment: thanks, its work. its "cefSharp package" problem and musts be run in x86